# How to use pipe with "sudo -ui"?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, sudo, remote

I have this command

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub | ssh root@[my_server] "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

How can I do the same thing but with `sudo -iu user1` before the 2nd `cat`? That is, I want to change a user after having been logged in.

Comment: This might help: `man ssh-copy-id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind getting the key on the screen as well (it is the public key, so this is not much of a security issue), you should be able to use `tee` to avoid redirection troubles along the lines of

```
cat  ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub \
| ssh root@server 'sudo -i -u user1 tee -a ~user1/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Comment: End the remote `tee` command with `>/dev/null` and you don't get the key written to _stdout_

Comment: @roaima ... or the pipeline, if you're ok with transferring the data to the local host just to throw it away. Also, the `cat` could be replaced by an input redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub | ssh root@[my_server] $'sudo -i -u user1 bash -c "cat - >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"'
```

Comment: what's the `$` for?

Comment: @Johsua It would interpret the string following as a "C string" and replace any `\n` or `\t` etc. with literal newline or tab characters.  However, in this instance, it would make absolutely no difference, so you may remove the `$`.

Comment: You could avoid the `bash -c` by using `sudo -u user1 tee -a ~user1/.ssh/authorized_keys >/dev/null`. Note that the `cat` is then also not needed.